# How to change bootstrap-tabe row background depending on its content

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

Let's say I want to change only the rows that have the word "Blog" in them to green or blue. See the example I have in jsfiddle. Is there a way to change the row color of a bootstrap-table depending on its content? :P

See this example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/16/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=e3nk137y)

```js
function rowStyle(row, index) {
    var classes = ['active', 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger'];
    
    if (index % 2 === 0 && index / 2 < classes.length) {
        return {
            classes: classes[index / 2]
        };
    }
    return {};
}
```

```html
<table data-toggle="table" 
       data-url="/gh/get/response.json/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/docs/data/data1/"
       data-row-style="rowStyle">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="name">Name</th>
        <th data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
        <th data-field="forks_count">Forks</th>
        <th data-field="description">Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: See jsfiddle link posted in the question for better output result.

Comment: Personally, I would use something like Knockout JS and just use css bindings to change the color based on the data contained. Completely dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function rowStyle(row, index) {
    const obj = {};
    if (Object.keys(row).map(key => row[key]).some(value => String(value).includes('blog'))) {
      obj.css = {'background-color': 'blue'};
    }
    var classes = ['active', 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger'];

    if (index % 2 === 0 && index / 2 < classes.length) {
        return Object.assign({}, obj, {classes: classes[index / 2]});
    }
    return obj;
}
```

See [updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/9699/).

Comment: Can you have a look at this? The table keeps loading for some odd reason. Does the data have something to do with that? http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/9727/

Comment: @NinjaShawarma Some of the values are numbers, so you should cast the `value` to string, see http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/9728/